# FFMPEG- add pauses in a video

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to add multiple pauses in a video file using ffmpeg? example: I would like to add a pause of 3 seconds from 5th second, then a pause of 8 seconds from 17th second. Audio file syncing is not an issue, just pause should be there at specified intervals.
Thanks.

Comment: See my [answer](https://superuser.com/q/1071369/114058) here for basic method.

Answer (score 0):

If my previous answer doesn't work you may need to cut up the source video and then overlay it on a blank canvas. Use the -filter_complex parameter to pass in the filtergraph you construct.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

```
the 'color' filter will give you a blank canvas with a 5 second duration
the 'trim' filter will allow you to get a stream containing only the first 3 seconds
the 'overlay' filter will allow you to overlay the first 3 seconds of footage onto the blank canvas repeating the last frame
```

This will give you your first scene

```
the 'concat' filter will allow you to join the scenes together

you can also use 'select' (see ffmpeg timeline editing)
to exclude the first 3 seconds of the source video for the second scene.
(You may need to import the same source video file twice
 so you can reference it as [0:v] to make the first scene 
 and [1:v] to make the second scene in the filtergraph if you run into problems.)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the loop filter in conjunction with the Timeline editing 'enable' parameter.
should allow you to craft a filter which loops a single frame for 3 seconds but is only enabled if the output timestamp is between 3 and 5 seconds.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loop

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing

Comment: An actual, usable example command would be very helpful in making this a better answer.